# ABAP TVRO field TRAZTD, Route Customizing Data

Tags: csv, abap, sap-erp, customizing

A customer of mine is looking to mass create some customizing data related the routes. and as such I have a small program which reads in a CSV file with all of the fields as they would be in the customizing transaction.

I'm having a particular problem wrapping my head around a field `TVRO-TRAZTD` for a couple of reasons.

The user is only filling in a number which represents a number of days.

- There is a conversion exit on `TRAZTD`, except it's obsolete, use `CONVERT TIMESTAMP` they say
- I don't have a timestamp, I have a decimal number representing a part of a day
- For example, `TRAZTD` would be entered as `0,58` from the CSV file, so why is it represented in the table as `135.512`?
- I tried it the old fashion way and multiplied `0,58 * 24` which gives me `13,92`. if I take `13,92 * 10` I get `139.200`, which isn't the same but it's the closest I can get, but I don't get it *why 10?*

Using the conversion exit even though it's obsolete doens't give me a result either, no matter number I give it I always get `0` back. I can't use the `convert timestamp` either because well, it's not a timestamp or I didn't look up carefully enough how to use it (I didn't see anything other than strings and characters).

The other thing I tried too was just saying "screw it" and placed the data from the CSV directly into the field and hoping the conversion routine will take care of the work, *but that doesn't happen either*.

Is there anybody out here that can maybe shed some light on where the number after the conversion comes from?

Answer (score 0):

everybody I came to a solution, just incase anybody stumbles upon this same problem.

I took the value from the excel document and multiplied it by 24 to get the amount of hours, and then multipled it 10000 because I don't know, I picked it randomly.